# Django Tutorial pub_date__year filter works and pub_date__second filter doesn't

Tags: python, django, django-models, python-2.7

I'm working my way through the Django tutorial, and I have a model as follows.

```
class Poll(models.Model):
    question = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
```

I constructed a Poll following the given instructions.

```
p = Poll(question="What's new?", pub_date=timezone.now())
p.save()
```

When I do the filter that they give, it gives me a valid result.

```
>>> Poll.objects.filter(pub_date__year=2013)
[<Poll: What's new?>]
```

But when I try to filter by second (for example), it fails.

```
>>> Poll.objects.filter(pub_date__second=57)
FieldError: Join on field 'pub_date' not permitted. Did you misspell 'second' for the lookup type?
```

Okay, so maybe the pub_date field somehow doesn't have a valid second.

```
>>> Poll.objects.get(id=1).pub_date.second
57
```

Hmm. So it does have a valid second, but somehow I can't filter with it. If I keep trying, __day and __month work fine, but __hour, __minute, and __second don't. Am I missing something in the syntax here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes If the documentation is up to date then these field lookups (second, hour, minute) are not yet in the main branch

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#hour

> New in Django Development version.

Which version of django are you running? 1.5? You can check out source on github

Comment: Yep, that was it. Checking out the source directly from GitHub worked (although it required installing pytz) -- I found https://code.djangoproject.com/attachment/ticket/8424/time_filters.diff and assumed that if someone had fixed it 5 years ago that it would have been in a commit by now :P Thanks!